# Twilio Web Client Multi Line Call

Tags: twilio, twilio-php, twilio-functions

I have a Twilio softphone that I am implementing and the basics functions are working great.
Please I would need to know how to implement a multi line call feature.

I would like to allow a agent in my browser softphone to put a call on hold and dial a different number then resume any call on hold when needed.

I actually have [image: Line button image]

Thank You

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you getting errors?

Comment: I have tried to add the active call to a custom queue as I could update later by queue sid to retrieve from queue. But the problem I have is when the call is "on hold", I cant make another call because twilio returns this error: `Twilio.Device Error: A connection is currently active`. I would like to be able to "hold" almost 5 calls and resume when I click back on the corresponding "Line x" button

Comment: Can you share the code, by updating your question, to show how you were putting people in a queue and on hold? Thanks!